# Prevent Thunderbird from automatically marking messages as read when deleted?

Tags: thunderbird

I prefer to manually mark new messages as read, to avoid accidentally having an important message go unnoticed or be misplaced.  To this end, I have disabled the option which automatically marks messages as read; in Thunderbird 52.5.0 this is found under *Options > Display > Advanced > Reading*.

However, when I delete a message it is moved to the Trash and automatically marked as read.  How do I preserve the unread status of a message when deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to solve this, and also so far no add-on (extension) which provides it.  The feature is requested in [bug 545504](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=545504).  Given the bug's history I'd say it's unlikely to happen soon, if ever.